# How to project 3D Human pose coordinates to 2D keypoints using Camera Matrix

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I've been trying to convert my 3D humanpose keypoints to 2D keypoints but I'm stuck at the camera matrix.
The keypoints I have in 3D contains the ideal viewpoint, I just want to paste it to the 2D plane thats it. I don't want to go into deeper camera processes.

What I have tried so far:

```
fx = 1
fy = 1
cx = 0
cy = 0
camera_matrix = np.array([[fx, 0, cx],
                          [0, fy, cy],
                          [0, 0, 1]], np.float32)
  
# Define the distortion coefficients
dist_coeffs = np.zeros((5, 1), np.float32)
  
# Define the 3D point in the world coordinate system
points_3d = np.array([[[arr[10,:,0], arr[10,:,1], arr[10,:,2]]]], np.float32).squeeze()
  
# Define the rotation and translation vectors
rvec = np.zeros((3, 1), np.float32)
tvec = np.zeros((3, 1), np.float32)
  
# Map the 3D point to 2D point
points_2d, _ = cv2.projectPoints(points_3d,
                                 rvec, tvec,
                                 camera_matrix,
                                 dist_coeffs)
  
# Display the 2D point
print("2D Point:", points_2d)
```

The above is giving some weird results so I tried a very basic approach:

```
camera_mat = np.array([
                [1, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 1]
            ])
points_2d = np.matmul(arr, camera_mat)
points_2d[:, 0] = points_2d[:, 0]/-points_2d[:, 2].mean()
points_2d[:, 1] = points_2d[:, 1]/-points_2d[:, 2].mean()
```

This gave expected results but when I switch human keypoints to hand keypoints, the results become worse. I want to solve this issue using some camera matrix. I don't think identity matrix is good to go here.

I'm not familiar with this camera processes as I'm focused more on neural networks. I'm looking for some solution which computes the camera matrix and computes the 2D keypoints assuming I only have 3D keypoints co-ordinates (no RGB images).

Thanks, please if you provide solution please provide easy to understand explanation as well as I'm very new to this topic.